# Razer Blade ubuntu 18 screen refresh issues

Tags: 18.04, display, screen

Please help.

I've got Ubuntu 18.04 dual booting on a Razer Blade 14. Generally ubuntu seems to work just fine until I use the Chrome browser.

When I scroll up or down the view is slow to refresh resulting in effects like the one pictured below:

[image]

I'd appreciate some help to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may sound counter-intuitive, but have you tried disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome? Disable it, restart your browser, and see if the behavior is still there. If it's still there, you can switch it back.

Comment: @KGIII: Thank you, that worked. I didn't know such a setting existed.
If you would like to provide an answer, I'll be happy to accept if.

Comment: Hardware acceleration shouldn't be enabled by default, but it is. I have no idea why. Anyhow, I typed up an answer along with directions for the next reader. The bugs render differently, so it's hard telling what the next visual bugs will be for the next person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for this one is quite simple.

Google Chrome, on Linux, has no hardware acceleration. On top of that, [Google has no plans to add it](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/10/hardware-acceleration-chrome-linux).

Why it exists as an option, and why it is enabled by default, are left as an exercise for the reader. The solution is to disable hardware acceleration and to restart your browser.

To disable it, open Chrome, click on the 3 vertical dots to open the menu, and then click on settings. On the left, click advanced and then on system. Disable hardware acceleration as in the image:

[image: disable hardware acceleration]

You'll need to close and restart the browser for the change to take effect. Once done, this and myriad other strange visual bugs will be a thing of the past.